# Chart.js compatibility to database

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

might be dumb question, but I'm really curious about Chart.js.
what kind of DB can access and can convert it to chart using Chart.js ?

and also, I'm looking for "how to connect mySql from javascript and shown on html" but I cannot see any topics about that. After googling for hours, I only found "connect with PHP" instead.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK Chart.js only handles the client-side rendering of charts. You have to retrieve your chart data from a DB somehow. This is typically done server-side (e.g. with PHP or whatever you prefer to use). So you have to fetch the data server-side and create your Chart.js chart based on the retrieved data. I'm not covering async updating of the charts right now but adding this as a side note!

Comment: so we can say that, Chart.js almost compatible with any database manager that has Client and server side, right?
and also, are we able connect database only using javascript?

Comment: Chart.js runs client-side. How and which data you present in the desired chart is up to you! As your question is very general, the used technology (servers-side) actually depends on your environment. But typically you read the data server-side which can be any as long as you pass the data in a form Chart.js supports. Client-side JS out-of-the-box does not support direct access on DB. This has to be handled server-side. There might be ways to use JS for accessing the DB with some sort of library etc. But typically client-side running code does not directly access the DB.